# SFTP processing from mainframe to server with Crush FTP software failing key authentication

Tags: sftp, mainframe

We are in the process of converting all FTP mainframe jobs to SFTP. I used the `ssh-keygen -f id_dsa_userid` command to create the key pairs. Sent the public key to client to be copied into their `authorized_keys` file. When job is executed, I get the following error.

> EZYXW11E XtlibError: invalidDisplay xtInitialize XtToolkitError
>         Can't open display: MVSDMC1
>   FOTS1370 Host key verification failed.
>   lost connection.

Client is using `CrushFTP` software which I know nothing about. What are we missing?

Comment: If you're the one providing the service, why is your client copying your public key to their `authorized_keys` file, not vice versa?

It appears that the server is not listed in the `known_hosts` file. Additionally, the error looks a bit like they're trying to start an X window session.

Comment: XtToolkit is a library for the X Server (graphical display), which should have nothing to do with SFTP. On the other hand, `ssh` can forward X connections. Guess: Something is setup wrongly wrt. to X forwarding, and tries to establish it, at least on one end. BTW, you can enable verbose debug messages on normal sftp/ssh clients/servers (e.g. `-v` for the standard `ssh`, `sftp`).

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue, but I've seen SSH fail if server and client time is not in sync -- 15 min. max difference, I believe. https://community.centrify.com/t5/Centrify-Express/Clock-skew-too-great-between-this-machine-and-the-domain-server/td-p/20832

Answer (score 0):

The problem at its root is in ssh and the key setup.  The X Windows Xauth problem is a Red Herring.  After found some additional research I found a thread that appears to match your [problem](http://community.dovetail.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1554).  The thread in question is for a product from Dovetail technologies but manifest the same problem in ssh key exchanges.

> EZYXW11E XtlibError: invalidDisplay xtInitialize XtToolkitError Can't open
>   display: 172.24.30.28:0.0 
>   FOTS1346 Permission denied, please try again. 
>   EZYXW11E XtlibError: invalidDisplay xtInitialize XtToolkitError Can't open display: 172.24.30.28:0.0 Connection closed by UNKNOWN
>   FOTS2707 zsshSmfWritePipe: write(): EDC5113I Bad file descriptor.  (errno2=0x05710034).

If the key is in place, the likely issue is incorrect permissions on the .ssh directory and files on the target system.  The following commands in the home directory of the `sftp` user will correct the permissions:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The permissions on my USS system look like this:

```
IBMUSER> ls -la
drwx------   2 IBMUSER  OMVS        8192 May 11 09:15 .ssh

IBMUSER> ls -la .ssh
-rw-------   1 IBMUSER  OMVS         399 May 11 09:15 authorized_keys
```